# Apache redirections redirect to directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is my problem, i want to redirect all request to `index.php` with `.htaccess`
My codes in `.htaccess` are :

first file in root directory :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ /public/ [R,L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

The second in public directory :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

when if i go to link i'm redirected to index.php but appear public directory and that is not good for my rooting class...
[image: Result]

How can i do to redirect to http://localhost:8888/my_project/ instead of http://localhost:8888/my_project/public/

Thanks for anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `R` (redirect) flag from root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /My_project/

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/My_project/public/$1/ -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks but only for public... I have an other problem, to access to css folder in public, uri is /public/css how is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand the question. What's the problem with css url?

Comment: the url localhost:8888/My_project/css redirect to localhost:8888/My_project/public/css/

Comment: How can i prevent it?

Comment: Sorry, i don't want prevent access (not for moment), just prevent redirecting to /public/css/ instead of /css

Comment: see updated answer. Test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: What happens when you enter a / after css e.g.: `localhost:8888/My_project/css/` (test in chrome dev tool)

Comment: /css/ don't redirect, /css yes how to prevent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82870/discussion-between-anubhava-and-phoenix).

Comment: where does css directory exist? Inside My_project/ OR My_project/public/?